# Invalid column name 'RN'

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to execute the following query but I am getting an error:

> Invalid column name 'RN'

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at ASC) AS RN, 
    user_id, created_at, followers_count,friends_count, statuses_count
FROM 
    dbo.master_users
WHERE
    RN = 1
```

Can anyone help me in this? I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: You can't use RN in the same query where you give the name (except of the order by clause). You must use all the expression in the where clause. Instead u can put the following `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at ASC) AS RN, user_id, created_at, followers_count,friends_count, statuses_count FROM dbo.master_users` in sub query and then use the RN

Answer (score 3):

you cannot use column aliases in where condition. Try this:

```
select * from 
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at ASC)
      AS RN, user_id, created_at, followers_count,friends_count, statuses_count
  FROM dbo.master_users
)
where RN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your response!